# Evenly spacing text and an icon within a snackbar

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

So I'm super new to all this (read: this is the first task I've ever been given), and I'm trying to style an icon and some text in a snackbar so that they're evenly spaced and properly aligned.

```
        <SnackbarContent
      message={
        <div>
        <i className='ri-checkbox-fill' /> 
        {general.snackMessage}             
        </div>
      }
      style={{
        backgroundColor: snackColor,
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'right',
        display: 'flex',
      }}
    />
```

The code above gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az9UK.png). I know I'm missing something super easy, but again as I've just started learning I don't even know where to begin on trying to get this working. Flex is treating them both as a single entity right now, and I've tried fragments, nested divs, etc to try and separate them out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply style to the div, not to the SnackbarContent